# Import data from db2 using informatica power Center without powerexchange

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

How to Import data from db2 table using informatica power Center without powerexchange.

Comment: I guess you can simply import the tables from PowerCenter Designer! Could you please elaborate where you are facing problem?

Comment: I am new to db2, i select source as export from DB2 but i am not sure how to move forward. Any steps as how to set details like database, creator, and tablename. So, far i have read db2 through power exchange only not sure how to read it through power center. Would appreciate if you could share the steps.

Comment: You do not need to export the tables from DB2, PowerCenter can connect to the DB2 database through ODBC and import the tables directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First open PowerCenter Designer, connect to the appropriate repository and open the folder in which you want to import the DB2 source.

Click on the Source Analyzer tab and follow the below instructions (from Informatica Designer Guide). Note that, you must have a ODBC Data Source created for the DB2 database from which you want to import tables.

> ### Importing Relational Source Definitions
>
> To create a relational source definition, use the Source Analyzer to import source metadata.
>
> To import a relational source definition:
>
> 1. In the Source Analyzer, click **Sources**> **Import from Database**.
> 2. Select the ODBC data source used to connect to the source database. If you need to create or modify an ODBC data source, click the **Browse** to open the ODBC Administrator. Create the data source, and click **OK**. Select the new ODBC data source.
> 3. Enter a database user name and password to connect to the database. **Note**: You must have the appropriate database permissions to view the object. You may need to specify the owner name for database objects you want to use as sources.
> 4. Optionally, use the search field to limit the number of tables that appear.
> 5. Click **Connect**. If no table names appear, or if the table you want to import does not appear, click  **All**.
> 6. Scroll down through the list of sources to find the source you want to import. Select the relational object or objects you want to import. 
>      You can hold down the Shift key to select a block of sources within one folder or hold down the Ctrl key to make non-consecutive selections within a folder. You can also select all tables within a folder by selecting the folder and clicking Select **All**. Use the **Select None** button to clear all highlighted selections.
> 7. Click **OK**. The source definition appears in the **Source Analyzer**. In the **Navigator**, the new source definition appears in the Sources node of the active repository folder, under the source database name

Answer (score 0):

(1) For design mode, you need create ODBC connection on your client computer where you run Informatica client. You need install DB2 client on your client computer, and catalog the DB2 database using DB2 configuration tool (you will find it in DB2 client folder after install). Then you can create ODBC connection to use the alias you just cataloged.

(2) For run-time mode, you need catalog the DB2 database on your Informatica server and create a connection in workflow manager. Assign the connection in session with the connection name.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create DB2 Source definition from DDL of the table.
2. Create the Relational DB2 Connection in the Workflow manager.
3. Get the connection string mapped to correct DB2 URL from your admin.
4. Choose the connection string just created in source properties.
5. Insert the User-name and password in the Relational connection.

   and you'll be able to connect to DB2.